Invalid anchor to a C++ member in Doxygen
I am trying to link to a C++ member variable in a RST document processed by Sphinx (let's call it X.rst). Another document (let's call it Y.rst) includes the Doxygen docs for the class in question:
.. doxygenstruct:: a::b::c::ClassName
   :project: ProjectName

Now, in X.rst, I try to do the following:
link to :cpp:member:`a::b::c::ClassName::name`

Once compiled, the HTML document X.html contains a link with an anchor. The anchor starts with a string _CPPv4 followed by a::b::c::ClassName::name with colons replaced by digits.
However, Y.html does not have such anchor. It has a number of <span id="..."></span>
entries with IDs almost matching the anchor from X.html: those IDs start with _CPPv2 and _CPPv3. Interestingly, there is also a link <a href="_CPPv4..."></a>.
What am I doing wrong? How can I get Sphinx to generate a link with an anchor starting with _CPPv2 or _CPPv3 or have another <span id="..."> entry starting with _CPPv4?
